# Doing A 301 Redirection

Tags: 301-redirect

Well just wanted to know if there is any way to do a 301redirection if my domain provider doesnt provide it. My domain provider is bigrock and hosted on blogger so it's big crappy for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the web server is running Apache with mod_rewrite and you have access to upload .htaccess files, you will be able to implement a redirect by using the following htaccess directives:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.somewebsite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.otherwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You would need to put this into a file named ".htaccess" and upload it to the root directory of the website, and obviously replace the domain names with your own.